# printer_open() not working in wamp 2.4 (PHP 5.4.16)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, printing

I am creating web-based software in codeigniter for one college to print out result of student here i created student module, marks module, and print Result module

In Print Result module i created single result print but now i want to print multiple result at once

for that I searched that printer_open is best to connect printer & print out document for that I download

```
php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip
```

form http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/and put it to ext directory and also put

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

in php.ini file but still it is showing error that

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in E:\wamp\www\exam\application\controllers\admission\forms.php on line 299
```

So please any one can help me to solve this problem
or is there anyother way to print multiple pages at once

Answer (score 0):

`printer_open()` should provide printer name as well.

If you don't know about your printer name, use `printer.default_printer`.

```
printer_open(printer.default_printer);
```

[Printer Parameter](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-open.php#refsect1-function.printer-open-parameters)

or else if you know your printer name, then try this

```
printer_open("HP Deskjet 930c");
```

[Printer Example](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-open.php#refsect1-function.printer-open-examples)

Comment: Ya Buddy I write printer name too like         printer_open("\\\\172.20.27.23\\Canon LBP2900");

Comment: just use `"Canon LBP2900"`

Comment: I Used it but It is showing that error and also it is my network printer

Comment: use `\\172.20.27.23\Canon LBP2900` make sure ip is correct

Comment: check whether printer is working. you can check by open MsWord and goto print, and get the address correctly

Comment: After changing some code i am getting error : printer_open(): couldn't connect to the printer [\\172.20.27.23\Canon LBP2900]